# Should HTML character codes or the symbols be used in the meta description?

Tags: html, symbols, meta, html-entities, html-encode

Can symbols like `™` and `®` go directly in the `meta`-`description` tag, or should their HTML character codes be used?

```html
<meta name="description" content="Hello® World™">

<meta name="description" content="Hello&reg; World&trade;">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use HTML character entities in meta tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290231/can-i-use-html-character-entities-in-meta-tags)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the character encoding of the HTML document allows it, use the characters directly. The HTML spec [recommends](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/document-metadata.html#specifying-the-documents-character-encoding) to use UTF-8 ("Authors should use UTF-8."), which is an encoding that allows this.

Relevant article from the W3C Internationalization Working Group:
[Using character escapes in markup and CSS](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes)

#### Some escapes are required

You must still use entities for characters that have a reserved meaning in HTML, if the context makes them ambiguous.

Examples:

- `<` (as `&lt;`)
- `>` (as `&gt;`)
- `&` (as `&amp;`)
- `"` (as `&quot;`)
- `'` (as `&apos;`)

#### Some optional escapes are useful

It can be a good idea to use entities for invisible characters (other than the common ones for space, tab, and new line), so that authors don’t confuse/overlook them.